# Get all possible permutations of bigger array

Tags: arrays, ruby, permutation

I am trying to take an array of strings `["-", "+", "*"]` and figure out all combinations of them for a given size. This is possible by doing the following:

```
arr = ["-", "+", "*"]
perms = arr.permutation(2).to_a
# => [["-", "+"], ["-", "*"], ["+", "-"], ["+", "*"], ["*", "-"], ["*", "+"]]
```

However, I want to get results for an array bigger than the given array. E.g., `arr.permutations(4).to_arr`. Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear. Do you want combinations or permutations?

Comment: I think I want permutations, but I'm not 100% certain as to the difference yet

Comment: Whoops. I had a typo. It can be reproduced now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
perms = arr.repeated_permutation(4).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not through any built in library or statistical method.

The Combination and Permutation methods implement standard probability theory functions.  That is, "A things taken B at a time."  You cannot create combinations or permutations using these standard methods to take more "things" than you actually have in the set.